Confused on how to conclude $n-a+1$.
Today I found out that for $a \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \left[\frac{k}{a}\right] = (n + 1 - \frac{a}{2})\left[\frac{n}{a}\right] - \frac{a}{2}\left(\left[\frac{n}{a}\right]\right)^2$$
Where $[x]$ is the floor function.
Is there a way to prove this? From this post on AoPs showed that it can be done using induction. But I'm having trouble after post #5 said "For $a \le n < 2a$ the left side is $n-a+1$",  I can't seem to verify that. Is there any hint I could use?

Hint: What is $[k/a]$ equal to when $k < a$? What about when $a \leq k \leq n < 2a$?

Put $a=3, n=12$ and work out LHS to understand what is happening.

$[\frac{k}{a}]$ should equal $0$ when $k<a$, but not sure with the other one...

@MyMolecules: Your numbers don't meet $n < 2a$. JAB: When $k > a$, what is the value of $[\frac{k}{a}]$ at least? At the same time, when $n < 2a$ and $k$ can go no higher than $n$, what is the value of $[\frac{k}{a}]$ at most? This is what Bruno B has revealed to you.

@jab: You can find a calculation of this sum as the first part of this answer.
